# how to remove &quot in js.erb to render javascript rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to append a javascript code to the body through file.js.erb. This is what i have written:

```
$("body").append("<script type='text/javascript'> method_1({'<%= current_user.selections.pluck(:name).each do |t| raw t end %>'});</script>");
```

But i always gives me an array with & quot; appended in the javascript code. I also tried using raw/html_safe. but it seems to throw no effect

I have tried other SO links, but it does not seem to help. I am using rails 3.

Comment: try use this `raw(t.to_json)` in `each` block or `t.to_json.html_safe`

Comment: this does not work either

Comment: this works good for me looks like you doing something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several trials, I understood that html_safe or raw are the methods of class String and I am using it on an array,also I removed equal(=) from the iterator, so this is how I am doing it now:

```
<% current_user.selections.pluck(:path).each do |t| %><%= raw(t) %>': true, '<% end %>'
```

Now, it works somehow.. Though I face some other problem such as getting an empty string at the end of the array, don't know why.. but at least that `&quot;` is removed

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition

```
{'<%= current_user.selections.pluck(:name).each do |t| raw (t.include?("&quot;") ? t.gsub("&quot;", "") : t) end %>'}
```

Comment: no, it does not seem to work. Same behavior is observed.

Answer (score -1):

Try this rails escape_javascript
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html